# StackLayout in WizardDialog and varying multiline Text with fixed height and dynamically showed scrollbar

Tags: java, layout, swt, jface, wizard

I am working on a wizard, which should have an error composite showed on the top of controls if an error occurs. This composite contains a `Text` listing all errors and two `Label`s: above and below this component. The `Label` below the error list can be omitted. Dependent on the amount of errors the height of the error list should vary. However it should not exceed the height of the parent composite. If the errors don't fit into the `Text` with the full height, a scroll bar should be shown.

Here's a minimized snippet of what I reached till now:

```
package de.dannylo.issues;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.eclipse.core.runtime.IStatus;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.Status;
import org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.MessageDialog;
import org.eclipse.jface.wizard.Wizard;
import org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog;
import org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardPage;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.custom.StackLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.ModifyEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.ModifyListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Point;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Rectangle;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Event;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Listener;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;


public class TestWizardPage
    extends WizardPage
{
    private static final String PLUGIN_ID = "de.dannylo.issues.TestPlugin";

    private Composite mainComposite;

    private Composite stackComposite;

    private StackLayout stackLayout;

    private Composite defaultMessageComposite;

    private Text idText;

    private static Wizard wizard;

    public TestWizardPage()
    {
        super("portalAppWizardMavenPage");
        setTitle("TestWizard");
        setDescription("Testing...");
    }


    @Override
    public void createControl(Composite parent)
    {
        mainComposite = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
        GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();
        mainComposite.setLayout(layout);
        layout.numColumns = 1;
        layout.verticalSpacing = 15;

        // source folder
        Composite idComposite = new Composite(mainComposite, SWT.NONE);
        idComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.NONE, true, false));
        idComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));
        Label label = new Label(idComposite, SWT.NONE);
        label.setText("ID:");
        idText = new Text(idComposite, SWT.BORDER | SWT.SINGLE);
        idText.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false));

        label = new Label(mainComposite, SWT.SEPARATOR | SWT.HORIZONTAL);
        label.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.NONE, true, false));

        stackComposite = new Composite(mainComposite, SWT.NONE);
        GridData layoutData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.NONE, true, false);
        layoutData.heightHint = 250; // For testing purposes in the real GUI
                                     // there are several components filling
                                     // this composite
        stackComposite.setLayoutData(layoutData);
        stackLayout = new StackLayout();
        stackComposite.setLayout(stackLayout);

        defaultMessageComposite = new Composite(stackComposite, SWT.NONE);
        defaultMessageComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        stackLayout.topControl = defaultMessageComposite;

        label = new Label(defaultMessageComposite, SWT.NONE);
        label.setText("Enter \"1\", \"2\" or \"3\"  into the text field above.");

        idText.addModifyListener(new ModifyListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void modifyText(ModifyEvent e)
            {
                if ("1".equals(idText.getText()))
                    showErrorComposite("You entered id 1", "Nice job!", createTestStatusList(4));
                else if ("2".equals(idText.getText()))
                    showErrorComposite("You entered id 2", "Oops", createTestStatusList(20));
                else if ("3".equals(idText.getText()))
                    showErrorComposite("You entered id 3", null, createTestStatusList(20));
                else
                {
                    stackLayout.topControl = defaultMessageComposite;
                    stackComposite.layout();
                }
            }
        });

        setControl(mainComposite);
    }


    private static List<IStatus> createTestStatusList(int amount)
    {
        List<IStatus> toRet = new ArrayList<IStatus>();
        for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
        {
            toRet.add(new Status(IStatus.ERROR, PLUGIN_ID, "Error message " + i + ": " + toRet.hashCode()));
        }
        return toRet;
    }


    private void showErrorComposite(String topMessage, String bottomMessage, List<IStatus> statusList)
    {
        final Composite errorComposite = new Composite(stackComposite, SWT.BORDER);
        final GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();
        layout.verticalSpacing = 20;
        errorComposite.setLayout(layout);
        errorComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.NONE, true, false));

        final Label topLabel = new Label(errorComposite, SWT.WRAP | SWT.BORDER);
        topLabel.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.NONE, true, false));
        topLabel.setText(topMessage);

        final Text errorList = new Text(errorComposite, SWT.MULTI | SWT.WRAP | SWT.READ_ONLY | SWT.V_SCROLL
                                                        | SWT.BORDER);
        final GridData gd_errorList = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.NONE, true, false);
        gd_errorList.horizontalIndent = 20;
        errorList.setLayoutData(gd_errorList);

        for (int i = 0; i < statusList.size(); i++)
        {
            IStatus status = statusList.get(i);
            errorList.append("\u2022 " + status.getMessage());
            if (i != statusList.size() - 1)
                errorList.append("\n\n");
        }

        final Label bottomLabel;
        if (bottomMessage != null)
        {
            bottomLabel = new Label(errorComposite, SWT.WRAP | SWT.BORDER);
            bottomLabel.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false));
            bottomLabel.setText(bottomMessage);
        }
        else
            bottomLabel = null;

        final Listener scrollBarListener = new Listener()
        {

            @Override
            public void handleEvent(Event event)
            {
                errorList.removeListener(SWT.Resize, this);
                int marginHeight = ((GridLayout)errorComposite.getLayout()).marginHeight;
                int stackCompositeHeight = stackComposite.getClientArea().height;
                int topLabelHeight = topLabel.getSize().y;
                int verticalSpacing = layout.verticalSpacing;
                int bottomLabelHeight = bottomLabel == null ? 0 : bottomLabel.getSize().y;
                int spaceAboveErrorList = marginHeight + topLabelHeight + verticalSpacing;
                int spaceBelowErrorList = bottomLabel == null ? marginHeight + 15 : verticalSpacing
                                                                                    + bottomLabelHeight
                                                                                    + marginHeight + 15;
                int hHint = stackCompositeHeight - spaceAboveErrorList - spaceBelowErrorList;

                Rectangle errorListClientArea = errorList.getClientArea();
                Point errorListSize = errorList.computeSize(errorListClientArea.x, SWT.DEFAULT, true);
                if (stackCompositeHeight < spaceAboveErrorList + errorListSize.y + spaceBelowErrorList)
                {
                    gd_errorList.heightHint = hHint;
                    errorList.getVerticalBar().setVisible(true);
                }
                else
                {
                    gd_errorList.heightHint = errorListSize.y;
                    errorList.getVerticalBar().setVisible(false);
                }

                errorComposite.layout();
                errorList.addListener(SWT.Resize, this);
            }
        };
        errorList.addListener(SWT.Resize, scrollBarListener);

        stackLayout.topControl = errorComposite;
        stackComposite.layout();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Display.getDefault().syncExec(new Runnable()
        {

            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                wizard = new Wizard()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void addPages()
                    {
                        addPage(new TestWizardPage());
                    }


                    @Override
                    public boolean performFinish()
                    {
                        MessageDialog.openInformation(getShell(), "Bye!", "Thanks for testing!");
                        return true;
                    }
                };
            }
        });
        new WizardDialog(wizard.getShell(), wizard).open();
    }

}
```

I have a problem with the ID2. In this case the height of the `Text` is maximum and the `bottomLabel` should be shown. Unfortunately this label doesn't appear as it's composite appears, but rather it appears only after the width of the window changes. It seems to be some problem with layouting. I already tried to use `errorComposite.layout(true, true)` (and even `getShell().layout(true, true)`) to flush the cache and redraw the children but this didn't help. Any ideas on how to fix that issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved your issue by entirely removing the `scrollBarListener` and fixing your layout a bit.

The `showErrorComposite(...)` method now looks like this:

```
private void showErrorComposite(String topMessage, String bottomMessage, List<IStatus> statusList)
{
    final Composite errorComposite = new Composite(stackComposite, SWT.BORDER);
    final GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();
    layout.verticalSpacing = 20;
    errorComposite.setLayout(layout);
    errorComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

    final Label topLabel = new Label(errorComposite, SWT.WRAP | SWT.BORDER);
    topLabel.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.TOP, true, false));
    topLabel.setText(topMessage);

    final Text errorList = new Text(errorComposite, SWT.MULTI | SWT.WRAP | SWT.READ_ONLY | SWT.V_SCROLL
                                                    | SWT.BORDER);
    final GridData gd_errorList = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
    gd_errorList.horizontalIndent = 20;
    errorList.setLayoutData(gd_errorList);

    for (int i = 0; i < statusList.size(); i++)
    {
        IStatus status = statusList.get(i);
        errorList.append("\u2022 " + status.getMessage());
        if (i != statusList.size() - 1)
            errorList.append("\n\n");
    }

    errorList.setTopIndex(0);

    final Label bottomLabel;
    if (bottomMessage != null)
    {
        bottomLabel = new Label(errorComposite, SWT.WRAP | SWT.BORDER);
        bottomLabel.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.BOTTOM, true, false));
        bottomLabel.setText(bottomMessage);
    }
    else
        bottomLabel = null;

    stackLayout.topControl = errorComposite;
    stackComposite.layout();
}
```

It now looks like this:

[image]

**UPDATE**

Ok, in your particular case, leave your code as it is and just add this line at the end of your `showErrorComposite(...)` method:

```
scrollBarListener.handleEvent(null);
```

Comment: This is a very good solution but it doesn't fill some of my requirements. The id1 should have the following layout: http://i.stack.imgur.com/B2moz.png No scrollbar, the `Text` has a size so that the content exactlty fits in it and the bottom label is placed right below the error list.

Comment: @DannyLo Ok, edited my answer. Actually, let me test that first.

Comment: Unfortunately changing these lines messes up the layout for ids 2 and 3. And i think I still need the listener to achieve showing the scroll bar only when its needed.

Comment: Thanks, that's quite funny and easy solution. Didn't expect it to be that short. I've got another question: To calculate the height hint for the error list I am adding the constant of 15 pixels to `spaceBelowErrorList` to make the layout look ok. I think the calculation should be right without that constant, but if I remove it, the error list takes too much space. Could you try it out and tell me what I am missing?

Comment: @DannyLo I don't know, sorry. I personally would go for the aproach I originally posted, because that will let the layouts handle everything.